# Can anyone identify this military radio?

Tags: united-states, transceiver, military-surplus

Hoping someone can identify the following military radio.

[image]

I spotted it at the curb and decided to make it a land-fill diversion project...

Comment: Welcome to ham.stackexchange.com!  Good on you for saving something interesting from the landfill.  There's no identification plate with a model or serial number on it anywhere?

Comment: The connectors on the back side are possibly also helpful for identification, so if you happen to have a photo of that too..

Answer (score 7):

One of the fine folks from [MMRCG](https://mmrcg.org) identified this as model R-1484/PRR-15

Comment: And a Google search for *R-1484/PRR-15* confirms this. Thank you, and welcome to this site. :-)

Answer (score 0):

This is indeed a R-1484/PRR-15, also known as AN/PRR-15. Made by Zenith, circa 1969 for USMC sigint use in Viet Nam. Probably fewer than 100 made.